# Can anybody generate opencv.js?

Tags: javascript, opencv, cmake

I can't generate OpenCV.js using this instructions: https://docs.opencv.org/master/d4/da1/tutorial_js_setup.html

I have this error:

> CMake Error: CMake was unable to find a build program corresponding to
>   "Unix Makefiles".  CMAKE_MAKE_PROGRAM is not set.  You probably need
>   to select a different build tool.

When I'm trying to execute:

```
python ./platforms/js/build_js.py build_js
```

Alright, guys! You can download opencv.js from sources (press F12) of this Page: https://docs.opencv.org/master/js_face_detection_camera.html

Comment: what OS are you using? you should give a little bit more details

Comment: Linux 3.13.0-144-generic #193-Ubuntu SMP Thu Mar 15 17:03:53 UTC 2018 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux; Ubuntu 14.04; cmake 3.10.1; Emscripten 1.37.36

Comment: The error message means that `make` utility in your system is absent or CMake isn't configured to use it. Which case is yours? (In other words, do you have `make` utility available?)

Comment: Yes, I have "make" utility.... I have had install cmake using "make" :) But I don't know how to configure CMake with using "make"...

Answer (score 34, accepted):

You can find a nightly build at https://docs.opencv.org/master/opencv.js and some useful stuff at https://docs.opencv.org/master/utils.js .

```
<script async src="https://docs.opencv.org/master/opencv.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Comment: Thank you! Buy I have this errors now: Error at Object.ensureErrnoError (https://docs.opencv.org/master/opencv.js:21:1723052) at Object.staticInit (https://docs.opencv.org/master/opencv.js:21:1723292) at cv (https://docs.opencv.org/master/opencv.js:21:1808024) at https://docs.opencv.org/master/opencv.js:58:10 at https://docs.opencv.org/master/opencv.js:14:15 at https://docs.opencv.org/master/opencv.js:16:2

Comment: There npm packages that contain compiled opencv.js, e.g., https://www.npmjs.com/package/opencv.js, https://www.npmjs.com/package/@mjyc/opencv.js, https://www.npmjs.com/package/@mjyc/opencv_wasm.js

Answer (score 3):

I'm still not able to build it from source.

But this version of **opencv.js** worked for me on MacOS https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/opencv.js

Comment: Here's a tutorial link if you'd still want to build from source: https://medium.com/@m.fortitudo.fr/how-to-install-opencv-js-c718d2add936

Answer (score 2):

I'll just list out the parts where installation was slightly different from what was outlined in https://docs.opencv.org/master/d4/da1/tutorial_js_setup.html.

For installing Binaryen, make sure you cd into the emsdk directory and then run these:

```
./emsdk install binaryen-master-64bit
./emsdk activate binaryen-master-64bit
```

From the official docs,

```
python ./platforms/js/build_js.py build_js
```

doesn't work because you need to add an additional flag --emscripten_dir to specify where the correct path. Note that you want the folder below the emsdk root directory, typically /fastcomp/emscripten/ (for the older “fastcomp” compiler; for the newer upstream LLVM wasm backend it will be /upstream/emscripten/).

*I personally used the /upstream/emscripten one*

So run this:

```
python /Users/fangran/opencv/platforms/js/build_js.py build_wasm --build_wasm --emscripten_dir /Users/fangran/emsdk/upstream/emscripten
```

And it should work and return:

```
=====
===== Build finished
=====
OpenCV.js location: /Users/fangran/opencv/build_wasm/bin/opencv.js
```

For more details: refer to this [link](https://medium.com/@m.fortitudo.fr/how-to-install-opencv-js-c718d2add936)

Answer (score 1):

Looks like Emscripten doesn't setup the enviroment variable correctly to the SDK

For anyone trying to get this to build you need to specify the correct path to the Emscripten

which is the path where Emscripten is installed found in `emsdk/upstream/emscripten`

```
python ./platforms/js/build_js.py build_js --emscripten_dir=/home/username/Desktop/emsdk/upstream/emscripten
```

This should then work

Comment: July 2021: The accepted answer and other posts did not work for me on MacOS. This post is the one that allowed the compilation to proceed. As a minor note, the '=' is not necessary. A space will do as well.