# Trying to get emscripten working in electron

Tags: node.js, electron, emscripten, webassembly

I am trying to get the [opencv.js](https://docs.opencv.org/master/opencv.js) emscripten port running in my electron app.
I found [this example of an app using opencv.js](https://codepen.io/huningxin/pen/NvjdeN), but when I try to integrate it into my electron project it just throws some cryptic error.

When I just try to require opencv.js I am getting

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: Module is not defined
    at opencv.js:33
    at Object.<anonymous> (opencv.js:5)
```

Also when I include it via script tag, like outlined [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49809421/457059).

In general I am having a really hard time finding proper documentation on how to load emscripten in electron.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Can you share more of your code? In particular the parts that instantiate the wasm module? But preferably can you share a full app?

Comment: what version of electron are you using?

Answer (score 2):

Upgraded from electron 3.1 to 5.0, now it works

Comment: did u package emscripten with an electron app? id like to create an electron app that incorporates a project on github, but the project on github uses emscripten and im not even sure i can get emscripten up and running portably with the electron app?

Comment: I gave up on this approach and used a native module instead @oldboy

Comment: which module exactly are you using?